# Xcode: Could not launch app on update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Fellow coders,

I have my iPhone App in version 1.0 that already is in the App Store, so everything works perfect in that version.

Currently I'm working on the update, version 2.0. Well, if I install this version as a completely new app on the iPhone, it works perfectly well. There are no issues on the app launch or any other errors at runtime.

But now the problem: If I already have installed version 1.0 and then try to update the app with version 2.0 (build and run in debug mode in Xcode), the app crashes immediately on launch. It's very confusing, since both versions work very well if they are built as independent apps.
Another interesting aspect is that the update works in the iOS Simulator, but not on the device.

Running the update on the device, I get one of the following errors (the errors are not always the same):

- failed to get the task for process xxxx
- Timed out waiting for app to    launch

Additional information to my Development environment: I'm using Xcode 4.4 on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8. The operating system on my iPhone is iOS 5.1.1.

I found out that the crash is caused before application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is called, so my actual source code can't cause the problem.

For those that are still interested in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Navigation bar

    UIImage *navigationBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"EMSNavigationBarBackground.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3.f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //Normal button

    UIImage *button30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"EMSBarButtonItemNormal"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *buttonHighlighted30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"EMSBarButtonItemPressed"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:buttonHighlighted30 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3.f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //Back button

    UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"EMSBarButtonItemBackNormal"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *buttonBackHighlighted30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"EMSBarButtonItemBackPressed"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBackHighlighted30 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3.f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: One way to get crashes on updates: is when you save some default values, then in the next version you change the way you check those values on application launch (e.g. you check some values to know which view to present, or similar). Example:in previous version, at application launch you were checking an object saved in NSUserDefaults for the key @"is_user_logged_in", then in the next version you use the key  @"is_logged_in", so in the previous version there was no such object for the "new" key, and your logic is down. Well that wasn't the best example, but think about it. Cheers

Comment: Exactly as above - there is something hanging around in documents folder or defaults that is confusing your update. Did you use Core Data then change the model?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Core Data with a new model version in the update, but I don't think that this causes the problem since the model migration works well in the iOS Simulator. It is really just a problem on the device.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea I posted the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. But that method isn't even called, so it can't cause a crash.

Comment: @JackHumphries No, I'm not working with the App Store version. I build and run both versions in debug mode.

Comment: @burki, put an NSLOG just before //Navigation bar in your "didfinishLaunching", to make sure it is getting called. If not, there must be something behind the launching process.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea I already did that, so I can say for sure that "didFinishLaunching" is not called.

Comment: then google for "didFinishLaunching is not getting called"

Comment: how did you test "update app from version 1.0 to 2.0"?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. The problem turned out to be the fact that I created a new project with a different name for the new version of the same app. Changing the project name back to what it used to be in the previous version, the issues were solved! Maybe this is also the case for your project? You can edit the name of your project as follows:

1. in your new project, select your target
2. in the utilities pane on the right, select the 'file inspector'
   tab
3. change the project name in the identity pane, this will open a
   new window which will help your refactor the project

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat similar problem. When I ran my app for the first time when previous version was installed I got "Timed out waiting for app to launch" error but the second time Xcode launched the app without problems. It turned out that the reason was that I had changed product name for target (select target, then on Build Settings tab set value for Product Name). However when I archived the app and installed on the device with iTunes it launched normally with the new name, so it seems that the problem was in Xcode.